# plotting each cluster with the same color

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, cluster-analysis

I am very new to machine learning python I am trying to make each cluster of my output with different color
here is the code:

```
mean = (1, 2)
cov = [[1, 0], [0, 1]]
x1, y1 = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 500).T

mean = (10, 2)
cov = [[1, 0], [0, 1]]
x2, y2 = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 500).T

mean = (5, 5)
cov = [[1, 0], [0, 1]]
x3, y3 = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 500).T

aa = [x1,x2,x3]
bb = [y1,y2,y3]


plt.plot(aa, bb, 'x')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

and this is the output I get

[image: output]

i need each cluster to have similar color but not all the same.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean:

```
plt.plot(x1,y1, 'x')
plt.plot(x2,y2,'x')
plt.plot(x3,y3, 'x')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: i need to make it using k mean algorithm, i made them but without using k mean, can you help ?